# Smoothest following animation in canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to make a coordinate (coord1) follow another coordinate (coord2) as smoothly as possible with these following conditions:

1. coord2 is able to move.
2. coord1 follows coord2 in the smoothest way possible (arc fashion).
3. coord1 follows at a constant speed.

I have an example here but it only succeeds condition 1 and 3 not 2. In the example, you can move the ball with your arrow keys.
[Click here to go to the example](https://jsfiddle.net/o5rshz1b/)

Here is my code for following:

```
Obstacle.prototype.follow = function () {
  this.y += this.vSpeed
  this.x += this.hSpeed

  if (this.x < ball.x - 9) {
    this.hSpeed = 1;
  }
  if (this.x > ball.x - 10) {
    this.hSpeed = -1;
  }
  if (this.y > ball.y - 10) {
    this.vSpeed = -1;
  }
  if (this.y < ball.y - 9) {
    this.vSpeed = 1;
  }
}
```

Anyone have a solution that succeeds all three conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow an object create a vector from tone object to the other. A vector has direction and length. The length is the speed and the direction is where it is going.

I have forked your fiddle to show this working. The only change is in the follow function.  https://jsfiddle.net/blindman67/ksu518cg/2/

```
// obj one 
var x1 = 100;
var y1 = 100;

// object to follow
var x2 = 300;
var y2 = 200;
```

Every animation frame the distance

```
var dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2-x1,2) + Math.pow(y2-y1,2));  // distance
```

Create a vector with length 1 pixel

```
var dx = (x2-x1)/dist;
var dy = (y2-y1)/dist;
```

Multiply by the speed you want to move

```
dx *= speed;
dy *= speed;
```

THen add to the objects position

```
x2 += dx;
y2 += dy;
```